# Cleaning tweets, issue with random letters and numbers in <>

Tags: r

I'm trying to clean tweets in R but there are some random numbers and letters in these <>.  I think the <> are emoticons from  twitter.  When I use the code below it cleans the tweet however, I'm left with random letters from within <>.    For e.g. <U+0001F1E8> when I use the code for cleaning twitter text I'm left with U.  This appears to be having an impact on my analysis.  How do I remove everything within <>?

For example I've tried `x_twt_txt_url2 <- gsub("[<\\D+\\d*>]", "", x_twt_txt_url)`and `x_twt_txt_url2 <- gsub("[+<:graph:>]", "", x_twt_txt_url)` and various combinations.  Can anyone help?

Example code below of cleaning twitter text:
#set text to lowercase
`x_twt_txt_lower <- tolower(x_twt_txt_url2)`

## Remove mentions, urls, emojis, numbers, punctuations, etc.

`x2_twt_txt_chrs <- x_twt_txt_lower`
`x2_twt_txt_chrs <- gsub("@\\w+", "", x2_twt_txt_chrs)`
`x2_twt_txt_chrs <- gsub("https?://.+", "", x2_twt_txt_chrs)`
`x2_twt_txt_chrs <- gsub("\\d+\\w*\\d*", "", x2_twt_txt_chrs)`
`x2_twt_txt_chrs <- gsub("#\\w+", "", x2_twt_txt_chrs)`
`x2_twt_txt_chrs <- gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", x2_twt_txt_chrs)`
`x2_twt_txt_chrs <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", x2_twt_txt_chrs)`

Comment: Can you post some reproducible sample data?

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you so much for your help.  Please see three tweets below as an example:                        Tweet 1 - France haven't had a lot of time on the ball <U+0001F633> #WorldCupFinal
Tweet 2 - In case it wasn’t already obvious why we must support France <U+0001F1EB><U+0001F1F7><U+0001F1E8><U+0001F1F2><U+0001F1E8><U+0001F1E9>C’mon Afrique! #AllezLesBleus #WorldCupFinal 
Tweet 3 - "replica goes to the winner original goes to Zürich <U+0001F643> #WorldCupFinal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Base R`:

```
gsub("<.+>", "", s)
[1] "France haven't had a lot of time on the ball  #WorldCupFinal"                                             
[2] "In case it wasn’t already obvious why we must support France C’mon Afrique! #AllezLesBleus #WorldCupFinal"
[3] "replica goes to the winner original goes to Zürich  #WorldCupFinal"
```

If you have tweets like this, where the chain of `<...>` strings is *interrupted* by stuff you want to keep:

```
"replica goes to the winner original goes to Zürich <U+0001F643> #WorldCupFinal <U+0001F643>"
```

you have to do this:

```
gsub("<[^>]+>", "", s)
```

This makes sure the match does not extend from the first `<` to the very last `>` thus also removing stuff in-between.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  Really appreciate it Chris.  I've been trying to solve for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)

s <- c("France haven't had a lot of time on the ball <U+0001F633> #WorldCupFinal",
       'In case it wasn’t already obvious why we must support France <U+0001F1EB><U+0001F1F7><U+0001F1E8><U+0001F1F2><U+0001F1E8><U+0001F1E9>C’mon Afrique! #AllezLesBleus #WorldCupFinal',
       "replica goes to the winner original goes to Zürich <U+0001F643> #WorldCupFinal")

s <- str_remove_all(s, "<[^()]+>")

s <- str_remove(s,'(?:\\s*#\\w+)+\\s*$')
```